# How can I slow down scroll on mac more than the system preferences let me

Tags: mouse, macos

I've gone into system preferences and made scroll as slow as it allows me to, but it's still way too fast.

I'm using a logitech mouse, but logitech's software doesn't seem to work.  What I'm wondering is whether there's some way to set the scroll speed to slower than the bottom of the slider, perhaps using terminal or something.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.smoothscroll.net/mac/ seems to work pretty well.  I'd be interested to hear if anyone has other suggestions though.

Comment: Are you able to use both your Logitech mouse and your trackpad to scroll?